# Graph theory - Barter nodes

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-theory

I have list of nodes where you can barter or convert one set of items to another set. For example -

NodeA:
Potato: 10kg, Water: 5kg, Sugar: 2kg -> PotatChips: 2Kg, Rice: 1kg

NodeB:
PotatoChips: 2kg, Water: 3 Kg -> Potato: 4 Kg, Rice 1 kg

NodeC:
PotatChips: 2Kg, Rice: 1kg -> Potato: 10kg, Water: 5kg, Sugar: 3kg

The objective is to select a list of nodes so that the sum of consumption is less or equal to than sum of production - ie you end up with a resource surplus or no loss for the resources associated with those nodes. For example if we choose NodeA and NodeC we end up with 1kg sugar surplus. But, if we choose NodeA and NodeB and we end up with a deficit of 5Kg water and 6kg potato.

Now we can try to put this nodes in a graph. However this is not your typical graph since the edges represent different units. Clearly if we try to put these node in a graph, we will see loops being formed. The surplus comes from going along the edges of multiple loops (possibly in parallel).

My current approach to this has been to solve this via an objective function and linear-programming. However I keep coming back to graph theory since this seems like a graph theory problem. What if we put all the nodes and try to find this cycles with a surplus. How would be represent the graph with different units? What algorithm detects such surplus loops?

**Is there a known representation or solution to this problem in graph theory?**

Constraint - We can't convert the different resources into equivalent single resource like money.

Comment: I do not understand the paragraph beginning "The objective is ..." What does a "resource surplus" mean?  Could you provide a couple of small examples where there is and is not a surplus?

Comment: @ravenspoint I edited the problem. Hope it it clearer now.

Comment: So, the node list is ordered.  The first node is "run" then the next node is "run" with the outputs from the previous.  OK.  But it seems that a node can be "run" several times.  Correct?  So, somehow your graph has to indicate multiple runs of a node - that will be tricky.

Comment: And, magically the first node has all its inputs available?

Comment: I am guessing that the outputs from one node can be used by several different nodes.  So your output would not be an ordered list but a tree.

Comment: @ravenspoint - Yes, the whole problem is tricky. The first node need not have all inputs available. We can start with a deficit and move into a surplus once the loops are complete. You are right that one nodes output can be fed into multiple outputs (including splitting each resource).

Comment: So, how do you choose which node runs when an output could be used by more than one node?

Comment: @ravenspoint You can choose all nodes or a subset of them. A node can also be chosen multiple times.

Comment: I guessed that you could do those things.  ( You should edit your question to clarify these points.  ) The point is what algorithm is used to select the nodes that will consume outputs that become available?

Comment: Is a solution guaranteed to exist? If multiple or infinite solutions exist (that are net positive on all resources, or at least net non-negative), do you have a way of picking the best solution? E.g., if solution A gave us +1 of all resources in 10 trades, and solution B gave us +2 of all resources in 100 trades, would we prefer A or B?

Comment: Is there any cost to moving between nodes? If there is, is it the same for every pair of nodes?

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion:

If you have Ni items ( water, sugar, etc. ) then create Ni different kinds of links.

Each node will have an in-link for each of the input items and an out-link for each kind out output.

When a node "sees" enough input quantity on its in-links then it "fires" and makes its outputs visible on its out-links

( This concept is modelled on neurons which fire when enough inputs are activated. )

Comment: This could starve some nodes. E.g. A and B both need X but A needs less, so A triggers and uses X before we ever get enough of X to trigger B.